# For painting/drawing models, what is the maximum exposure time and maximum light intensity of a spot shining in your eyes at a fixed position?

Tags: eye, vision, ophthalmology, light, eye-strain

For painting/drawing models, what is the maximum exposure time and maximum light intensity of a spot shining in your eyes at a fixed position?

That is: before the damage to your eyes becomes unrepairable?

Is the light intensity actually the problem, or is it purely the heat which causes the problem?

**Clarfiication edit:** A painting/drawing model is a person exerting a modeling discipline. Contrary to a photography model, a painting model performs for one or more painters/drawers who will use the model's body as an inspiration for their artistic works.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by painting models?

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks. I have answered your question in a "**clarification edit**". I have now also included "drawing models" into the terminology, so as to further clarify.

Comment: I'm still unclear. Are you asking how long a model can sit under a bright spotlight, or are you envisioning some sort of light that's focused tightly on their eye or is extraordinarily bright?

Comment: @CareyGregory The second option. I am interested in permanent eye damage due to a continuously focused artificial light source.